# From curl to jQuery’s $.ajax() Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to convert the curl code from an API called TextRazor to jquery's AJAX because of a platform limitations. I have tried many solutions from similar questions by the community but can't seem to get any data back (through the alert dialog). If it matters 
from the documentation calling the API looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-textrazor-key: YOUR_API_KEY" \
-d "extractors=entities,entailments" \
-d "text=Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell off..." \
https://api.textrazor.com/
```

My current AJAX code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.textrazor.com/",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
data: { 
   x-textrazor-key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
   extractors: "entities,entailments",
   text:"Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell..." 
},
success:function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
},error: function(xhr) {
    alert("<some error>");
    console.error(xhr.responseText);
}});
```

here is the link to jsfiddle if it helps: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/8k8b647g/)

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

This looks close to me, but you put the header into the POST body. I think it should be the below. (Note that you also need quotes around 'x-textrazor-key', since the dashes in it will otherwise be interpreted as subtraction.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.textrazor.com/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
       'x-textrazor-key': "YOUR_API_KEY"
    },
    data: { 
        extractors: "entities,entailments",
        text: "Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell..." 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("<some error>");
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

There could of course be other issues here. (E.g. perhaps the API doesn't support cross-origin requests.) You'll want to take a look at the network tab in your browser's developer tools to see what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass "x-textrazor-key: YOUR_API_KEY" as additional header

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.textrazor.com/",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('x-textrazor-key', 'YOUR_API_KEY');},
data: { 
   extractors: "entities,entailments",
   text:"Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell..." 
},
success:function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
},error: function(xhr) {
    alert("<some error>");
    console.error(xhr.responseText);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: { 
   x-textrazor-key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
```

The data: bracket in jQuery means that you want to send that data as POST, while you need to send the API key as a header.

Add this field to your code (after URL or so):

```
headers: {"x-textrazor-key": "YOUR_API_KEY"}
```